# Find an equation of the line tangent to a curve

Tags: calculus

**Problem:**

Find an equation of the line passing through the point $(0,18)$ and tangent to the curve $y = x^3 + 2$ at some point.

**Attempt:**

So $\frac{dy}{dx} = 3x^2$ and the equation of the line is $b = (3x^2)a + 18$, however I don't know where to proceed from there.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 3):

**hint to finish**

The equation of the tangent to the curve at the point $(x_0,y_0) $ is

$$y=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+y_0.$$

the point $(0,18)$ lies in this line, thus

$$18=(3x_0^2)(0-x_0)+(x_0^3+2) $$

or
$$16=-2x_0^3$$
and
$$x_0=-2$$

Answer (score 1):

If the point of tangency is at point $(a,a^3+2)$, then according to the first derivative of the curve, the slope of the tangent is

$$m = 3a^2$$

The tangent passes through $(0,18)$, so the slope is

$$m = \frac{(a^3+2)-18}{a-0} = \frac{a^3-16}{a}$$

Equating the two,

$$\begin{align*}
3a^2 &= \frac{a^3-16}a\\
2a^3 &= -16\\
a &= -2\\
m &= 12
\end{align*}$$

By slope-intercept form, the equation of the line is

$$y = 12x + 18$$